# What icon conveys "results"?

Tags: icon, symbolism

I'm looking for an icon to convey results.

There seems to be a lot of them online, but the vast majority of them fits the concept of financial results. I'm looking for one that will fit in with sports results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trophy or a checkered flag would usually indicate the sporting event is over and the results are in.

[image][image]

<sup>From Google Images</sup>

Comment: Or, depending on context, medals or a podium.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go for a podium (of a much more sophisticated version than this):

[image]